# Who do I need to bribe to propagate MSO privilege wiki changes across SE?

Tags: support, privileges

Long ago I updated [the privileges page for the 10 tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) to explain flag handling, but [it hasn't propagated yet to other sites.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) Apparently, [10k users now see a flag count as well](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=1733311#1733311), so flag handling has become especially relevant now.

Who do I need to bribe to make this change propagate?

(Oh, by the way. The [flag post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) privilege page is also quite out of date, for whoever feels like updating it.)

Comment: short answer: Waffles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bribe:

[image: waffles]

I prefer to be bribed with maple syrup:

[image: bribe]

Comment: synced it up ... to be deployed today

Comment: I'm confused. Are seals allergic to maple syrup? Is it like their kryptonite? And if so, does that make them the arch-enemy of waffles?

Comment: Yes Yes and Yes